# Issues using SpringBoot with Java 10 Module System

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, java-platform-module-system

I've just generated a project from http://start.spring.io/ (Using the full version mode). There I basically selected:

- Gradle project
- Java (right bellow I selected Java Version 10)
- SpringBoot 2.0.3
- NetFlix stack

It generates the sample project normally.
But after running gradle eclipse plugin in order to generate the `.project`, it generates the project in the "legacy" way with dependencies in classpath instead of using the module path.

Searching in the internet, I've found following code to be added in `build.gradle` in order to put the dependencies in the module path.

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged {
                entries.findAll { isModule(it) }.each { 
it.entryAttributes['module'] = 'true' }
            }
        }
    }
}

boolean isModule(entry) {
    // filter java 9 modules
    entry.kind == 'lib'  // Only libraries can be modules
}
```

After that the project has been generated with the dependencies on module path and i was able to make it green (of course by adding the respective module-info.java).

I've enhanced the compileJava task with following as well:

```
compileJava {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
        ]
        classpath = files()  
    }
}
```

The problem starts when I try to run the Application through eclipse, first I got following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for 
C:\xxxxxx\modules-2\files-2.1\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.4c\19d4e90b43059058f6e056f794f0ea4030d60b86\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer not in module
```

There is something that can be done to overcome this?

I've removed such dependency (`xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar`) from the launcher just to see what happens, then I got following exception:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules aws.java.sdk.sts and aws.java.sdk.autoscaling export package com.amazonaws.auth.policy.actions to module backend
```

So it looks like that the SpringBoot 2.0.3 dependencies aren't prepared to run in module path. Is that right? I missed something here?

By the way, I'm using:

- JDK 10.0.1
- Gradle 4.8
- Eclipse Oxygen 3a